# Grokking the word `scheme` in URI

Tags: vocabulary, usage

A generic form of URI is:

> scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]

scheme here means protocol which whereas has no relation to its original definition.
I cannot really understand it intuitively.

In wikipedia [Uniform Resource Identifier - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Examples)

> Examples of popular schemes include http(s), ftp, mailto, file, data, and irc. URI schemes should be registered with the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA), although non-registered schemes are used in practice.[b]

I can understand it's meaning. I cannot interpret it usage why 'scheme' is used instead of 'protocol'.

Scheme in MW dictionary:
[Scheme | Definition of Scheme by Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scheme)

> 1.a concise statement or table
>
> 2.a plan or program of action;
>
> 3.a systematic or organized configuration

in Oxford:[scheme | Definition of scheme in English by Oxford Dictionries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scheme)

> 1.A secret or underhand plan; a plot.
>
> 2.A particular ordered system or arrangement.

It seems 'A particular ordered system or arrangement' make sense.

If it does, an ordered system or arrangement should comprise the completed URI. 
'scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]' should be renamed as 'scheme' not URI.

So, what's the original meaning of the word to which 'scheme' here relate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Oxford's definition 2: An ordered system or arrangement.

FTP and HTTP, for example, are ordered systems for accessing data. The URI developed from the URL, which was originally designed to encompass these and a couple other systems for accessing the internet.

People who write standards would rather keep things consistent than make every word used fit its use in day-to-day speech, so when URI's to refer to local files or triggering actions like launching an email program were added, they might rather keep using the word *scheme* than change it.